# Laravel 5: custom routing

Tags: php, laravel, routes, laravel-5

I have a site that I'm building which has two different types of components: `pages` (static files with images and text) and `forms` (dynamic documents which take input). I will be creating and editing both of these via an admin panel, so there will be a Repository model and controller for each one.

It would be quite easy in Laravel to create routes like the following:

```
Route::match(['get', 'post'], '/pages/{one?}/{two?}/{three?}', 'PagesController@loadPage');
Route::match(['get', 'post'], '/forms/{one?}/{two?}/{three?}', 'FormsController@loadForm');
```

Unfortunately this would lead to some ugly URLs for people using the site:

- http://www.example.com/pages/
- http://www.example.com/pages/about-us
- http://www.example.com/forms/contact-us

I would prefer to remove "pages" or "forms" from these links then check the database to figure out which one to load:

- http://www.example.com/
- http://www.example.com/about-us
- http://www.example.com/contact-us

I created a `Path` eloquent model with two properties: `path` and `controller`. So I currently have the following:

```
Route::match(['get', 'post'], '{one?}/{two?}/{three?}', function() {
    $path = Path::where('path', '=', implode('/', func_get_args()))->take(1)->get()->first();
    // Somehow use $path->controller to load the proper controller
});
```

I've tried using `App::make($path->controller)` but it throws the error: "Class PagesController does not exist"

I believe I can use middleware to modify the request before it reaches my app (thus pre-pending "pages/" or "forms/" accordingly without modifying the URL seen by the user) however I can't find a way to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple thing to do is to check the url pattern against a database record. That's what I do with simple urls which represent complexe website structure. You can use a table which stores the url string and the url type (page, form...), each url being unique.

Answer (score 0):

I have made a test to full fill this requirement. Hope you will find this help full.

My route looks like: just in case Get method:

```
Route::get('test/{param}', array('as' => 'test1', function(){
    return "glade to see you here....1";
}));
Route::get('test/{param}', array('as' => 'test2', function(){
    return "glade to see you here....2";
}));
```

and my html look like:

```
{{link_to_route('test1',"test1",1)}}
{{link_to_route('test2',"test2",2)}}
```

Well let me rephrase that, my concern here define similar route with different name, and also call them through their name. By this approach you can achieve your requirement.

However you can define your with different name and whatever your route look alike, let me know if its still unclear to achieve your goal.

Comment: Unfortunately this does not meet my requirements. This allows you to make links to routes with the same path, but it does not allow you to create separate paths with the same base name using an Eloquent model for redirection. In your example there is no way to *directly navigate* to the first closure ("glade to see you here....1") - loading http://www.example.com/test/test1 returns "glade to see your here....2"